# OpenCV SVM prediction confidence with 3 classes

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, svm

I really need to know the confidence of my prediction, and OpenCV's SVM predict method does give me the option of "[returnDFVal](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-predict)":

> returnDFVal – Specifies a type of the return value. If true and the
>   problem is 2-class classification then the method returns the decision
>   function value that is signed distance to the margin, else the
>   function returns a class label (classification) or estimated function
>   value (regression).

Unfortunately, I have 3 classes, so this doesn't work for me. Is there any way I can get around this or another method I can call to determine the confidence of my prediction?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do something like this?

Comment: No, I ended up solving the problem with the deep learning library Caffe which handles pixels and the 2D nature of an image and gave me a confidence interval.

Answer (score 2):

Prediction probabilities are not possible yet, but there is a way to get it from under the hood `libsvm`, please find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62969615/3994228).

Answer (score 1):

With opencv 3.x:

```
float distanceSample(cv::Mat &sample)
{
        assert(svm != NULL && svm->isTrained());
        assert(!sample.empty());

        cv::Mat result;
        svm->predict(sample, result, cv::ml::StatModel::Flags::RAW_OUTPUT);
        float dist = result.at<float>(0, 0);
        return dist;
}
```

...

```
float dist = distanceSample(yourSample);
float confidence = (1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-dist)));
```

PS. This works only for 2-classes classification.