# Get a probability out of svm

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, probability

I have trained an SVM with 6 classes.

Is it possible to get a probability when using an SVM in OpenCV?

Thank you.

Comment: CvSVM::predict will give an estimated function value.

Comment: predict returns the predicted class not the probability                           float res = svm->predict(testDataMat);

Comment: i would like to get the probability as a result

Comment: how can i get the distance betwen each point and the hyperplan?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OPencv SVM predict probability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782979/opencv-svm-predict-probability)

Answer (score 1):

SVM doesn't provided probability for the output class, rather its gives Euclidean distance for the predicted class.

Following `predict` call will return you **class number** via `pred`:

```
cv::Mat pred;
cv::Mat sample; 

...
svm->predict(sample, pred);
```

and Following would give you the **Euclidean distance** via `pred`:

```
svm->predict(sample, pred, cv::ml::StatModel::RAW_OUTPUT);
```

Answer (score 0):

The SVM is not a probalistic classifier, so there is no acutal probability you can obtain. What you can get from the SVM is a score value: `returnFDValue` This value can be interprated like a probability.

```
double cv::ml::SVM::predict(const cv::Mat & data, double & returnFDValue);
```